# Foundation sticky header first scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation, sticky

I'm using [Foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and the [sticky header](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html).

Here is my code:

```
<header>
  <div class="sticky">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
      <!-- Blablabla -->
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

The problem with this version is that **when I scroll down for the first time**, the sticky header doesn't work. I have to scroll down, then up to the top of the page and after the sticky header works.

After that, I've add the class fixed `<div class="sticky fixed">` but once the page is loaded, this hide my element on the top of the page instead of going above them.

So my workaround is to add, then remove the class `fixed` after the page has been loaded. With that change, the header gets sticky during the first scroll, but it looks like to not be the perfect solution, and it has side effects :/

```
$('header .sticky').addClass("fixed");
$('header .sticky').removeClass("fixed");
```

Another solution is to fixe the header and apply a `margin-top` to all elements. But we loose the benefits of the `sticky` class.

Any idea for a better solution / find the source of the issue?

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Is your topbar at the top of your page to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using `.sticky` when you only need to use `.fixed`. The difference is:

- `.fixed` is for when the `topbar` is positioned at the top of the page.
- `.sticky` is for when the `topbar` isn't at the top of the page.

If your `topbar` starts at the top of the page use:

```
<div class="fixed">
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
      <!-- Blablabla -->
    </nav>
  </nav> 
</div>
```

If your `topbar` starts at a position down the page use:

```
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="sticky_on: large">
    <!-- Blablabla -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I ended up doing. Thanks for the clarification!